# Getting error while trying to display some strings from an array

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm working on an angular project and I needed something like a wheel for winning prizes or getting random
products.

I tried to implement it inside my project but some data are not displayed properly.

here is my code :

```
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  ViewEncapsulation,
  Input
} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-wheel",
  templateUrl: "./ngx-wheel.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./ngx-wheel.component.css"],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Emulated
})
export class NgxWheelComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() colors: Array<string>;
  @Input() fontColor: any;
  @Input() arrowColor: any;
  @Input() spinOnce: Boolean;
  @Input() spinRange: Array<any>;
  @Input() prizeToWin: string;
  @Input() centerText: string;
  @Input() prize_descriptions: Array<string>;
  @Input() stroke: string;
  @Input() strokeWidth: number;
  ngOnInit() {

  }
}
```

the html :

```
<ngx-wheel [prizeToWin]="iPhone" [prize_descriptions]="['Car','iPhone','$200']" [colors]="['#ff0000', 'green', 'blue']"></ngx-wheel>
```

What I get :

[The wheel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLxJx.png)

Comment: What is the logic here to determine what is to be displayed?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to add the following attri utes to your wheel component :

- [centerText] // text in the middle of the wheel
- fontColor // font color of each element

[Source](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-wheel)

Answer (score 0):

Please find the ngx-wheel API [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-wheel).

Edit you template accordingly below and it should work properly

```
<ngx-wheel [centerText]="YOUR TEXT HERE" fontColor="white" [prizeToWin]="iPhone" [prize_descriptions]="['Car','iPhone','$200']" [colors]="['#ff0000', 'green', 'blue']"></ngx-wheel>
```